# Passing datareader value to global string c#

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to pass the data from the datareader to a global variable, but for some odd reason when I do an alert to show the value it shows up as blank. Am I just not passing it correctly?

```
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(SQL))
        {
        connection.Open();

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 Number FROM TestTable.dbo.users WHERE LoginName ='" + viewerUserNameTxtBox.Text + "'", connection))
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
             while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string test = reader.GetString(0);
                    viewerNumber = test;
                 }
            }
        }
```

So I have a global variable:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

/* Global Variables Start */
string viewerNumber = "";
```

This is how I show the alerts:

```
        protected void variableCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + viewerNumber + "');", true);

}
```

Comment: You're assigning it just fine, that's what `variable = assignment` does. Set breakpoints, step through your code and inspect that your assignment actually executes. Also, please read [ask] and show all relevant code, i.e. where you call above code and how you show the alert. It also isn't a global variable, FYI.

Comment: This code is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: How you are showing the alert? post that code as well.

Comment: I just posted how I display it.

This code is being used internally so no worry of sql injection attacks.

Comment: Web is stateless and so you need to maintain state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's **not** a global variable. That is a class-level variable. Remember that *every single postback uses a new instance of your page class*. Any time a new server event is called, that's a new postback, a new instance of the page class, and a complete run for the *entire* page life cycle (including Page_Load and friends).

For web sites, you should put this data in the session instead. You should also fix that horrible awful sql injection issue:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(SQL))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 Number FROM TestTable.dbo.users WHERE LoginName = @UserName;", connection))
{
    command.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = viewerUserNameTxtBox.Text
    connection.Open();

    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string test = reader.GetString(0);
            Session["viewerNumber"] = test;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will fix the SQL injection issue instead of being lazy, this was an internal site so I was not fearing it but I shouldn't be lazy!

Answer (score 0):

Also if your messages are not showing up you could actually write your own method that handles the Javascript Alert this way.. another alternative to by passing the ScriptManager

```
public static void ShowClientMessageDlg(string msg, string aValue, string redirect = "")
{
    string msgFormat;
    msgFormat = string.Format(" {0}", aValue);
    msg = msg + msgFormat;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('" + msg + "');</script>");
}
```